# Project Creation Failed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have been using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for a while when one day I go to make a new project and it comes up with "Creating project 'XInput' ... project creation failed" down the bottom of my screen.

I have been scouring the internet for many days to find a solution to this with no luckso I will list what I have done.

- Changed my registry file permissions
- Ran as Administrator
- Made a new account
- Uninstalled, reinstalled and once again uninstalled Visual Studio
- Installed Visual C++ 2010 Express
- Deleted the registry files and recreated them
- Tried saving the project not on my external hard drive but my internal
- Attempted looking at and editing the config file

I am able to open existing project but I just cant open any existing ones. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)