# Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express Project creation failing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, project, 32-bit

After installing Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express, I have not been able to create any projects. Visual Studio Basic 2010 Express was previously installed. 
  I constantly am getting the error after putting the name into my project and selecting the type;

> Creating project "*project-name*" . . . project creation failed.

I did check the settings for the project templates and items, they seem to be pointing to my documents folder instead of my *ProgramFiles*, but I am sure that it did not work even there.

Another question similar to this one:
[Project Creation Failed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169372/project-creation-failed-microsoft-visual-c-2010-express-and-visual-studio-2010)

Any suggestion is thanked, I have been trying to find a solution to this for a very long time, but have not been able to find anything helpful.

Many thanks, 
Jim

Comment: It didn't install properly, registry damage is invariably the root cause.  You'll need to get your machine stable again.

Comment: Alright. This is an older desktop that I am using, soon I will be restoring it completely.